# Fire code drywall

Tags: drywall

I am working on a older home that has half inch fire code drywall I cannot find this anywhere the only size I can find is 5/8 fire code drywall does anyone know if they still make the half inch I know that used to make quarter inch 3/8 and half inch but now they've switched all to 5/8 but can you still get half inch fire code wall because regular drywall I only need to replace one piece in the room it will be look different with the texture

Comment: Probably because fire codes have been revised and now require 5/8?  If so, since this is a repair, the rest of the wall will be grandfathered and you should be able to use 1/2, which I do know is sold.

Comment: Are you asking whether half-inch fire-rated drywall is available, or is there more to the question?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is what's currently known as type C firecode. This board has improved burn rating to what's probably there (type X) info: http://www.awci.org/cd/pdfs/8309_f.pdf

You can purchase type C in 1/2" or 5/8".